# Nodejs download does not start in browser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, download

I'm trying to create an excel file in my nodejs server and send it to the client, but for some reason the download refuses to start even though the data contains the file

Is there something I'm missing when trying to serve files with nodejs server?

Here is the releant code in my server:

```
app.get('/excel', luoExcel);


function luoExcel(reg, res){
        var tiedosto = new excel.Workbook();
        var välilehti = tiedosto.addWorksheet('Maksamattomat');

        var style = tiedosto.createStyle({
                font:{
                  size: 12
                },
                numberFormat: '$#,##0.00; ($#,##0.00); -'
        });

        x=1
        for(row in reg.body){
                n = 1;
                for(column in reg.body[row]){
                        välilehti.cell(x,n).string(reg.body[row][column]).style(style);
                        n += 1;
                }
                x+=1
        }
        tiedosto.write('Testi.xlsx', function (){
                var path = __dirname + '/Testi.xlsx';
                res.download(path);
        });
}
```

Here is my client side code:

```
    $scope.lataaExcel = function(){
            $http.get('/excel', $scope.maksamattomatLista)
             .then(function(res){
                    console.log(res);
            }, function(error){
                    console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: You don't get `req.body` in a `GET` request

Comment: Thats true. Looks like I'm not able to send the list with get message and I'll have to do it purely in server side

Comment: No. Just do a POST request. Post requests have body.

Comment: I actually tried it with POST request first, but in that case the browser wouldn't start the download. I thought that it would only start it if it was done with GET-request.

Comment: Is it possible that there is something wrong with my middleware so that it eliminates headers associated with download? Because if I browse to the page containing the XML-file in the browser it is shown in text format on the web page with no download popup.